# How to register for a c# event in unmanaged code using c++/cli

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I have an event fired from a c# component and another c++ component needs to register for this event and catch this event. I am using C++/CLI as a mediator to access other functions of this component.Though there is a code available for the other way round not much for the other way round.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25524/Sinking-events-from-managed-code-in-unmanaged-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a C# class

```csharp
public class Foo
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    protected virtual void OnMyEvent(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = MyEvent;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

and a C++/CLI class

```cpp
public ref struct Bar
{
public:
    void handler(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
    {
    }
}
```

then you should be able to add an event listener as follows

```cpp
Foo^ foo = gcnew Foo;
Bar^ bar = gcnew Bar;

foo->MyEvent += gcnew EventHandler(bar, &Bar::handler);
```

*(Untested)*

Comment: It works! I just had to add an instance of Bar in my cpp class.